# Extract images from .swf viewer?

Tags: image, flash, extract

I'm wondering how it possible to extract images from .swf viewer?
Note that .swf file have not images itself.

For example I'm trying extract images from AVON catalogue from this link - http://avon.com.ua/PRSuite/eBrochure.page?index=1&cmpgnYrNr=201404&pageNo=0

Any ideas?

Comment: check if the swf loads the images or has them embedded. if the images are embedded, you might have a few options: a commercial swf decompiler(like sothink's one), [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) SWFDump tool, or you could load the swf from your own swf and use the [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) library to get the resources you need from the loaded bytecode

Comment: I've checked that and figured out that swf loads images. In this case Is it possible to extract images?

Comment: if you figured out that the images are loaded, you can probably see the paths to them, right ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I downloaded swf file and did't see any images. Here is that file - http://static.avon.com.ua/PRSuite/static/ebrochure/Framework/uk_UA/Avon_EBrochure.swf

Comment: How did you figure out that the swf loads images ?

Comment: I downloaded swf file to my HDD and opened it with web browser (I tried Safari, Chrome, Firefox). I saw that swf hasn't any images. In my previous comment I paste the link to that swf file.

Comment: Ok, do this: Open the site in Chrome > Tools > Developer Tools. In the  network tab you'll resources loaded (from pages.xml) as you click though the swf to view contents. Notice also the images load (e.g. 006,026.jpg, etc.)...Right click > open link in new tab

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza It does not consist of any mentions of jpg, png or gif files.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza oh, wait. When changed pages I found some pictures but it is not all of them.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks a lot. I finally figured out a path where server stores his images. How can I vote for your comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way is to put the .swf file in a decompiler for image extraction. Decompilers are smart enough to extract images for you and arrange them.

JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler is a more popular one
http://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/ 
You can extract other useful content from it as well.
Just download the .swf file from the website

Comment: FYI, as of 2015-05-13, Symantec End Point protection is blocking the Windows Installer *.exe file as it thinks it's malicious.

Answer (score 3):

A while back (like around 1999) I wrote a set of tools for Flash animations.

One of the tools is `swf_dump` which can be used to extract objects (i.e. write the objects in a form of script that sswf can nearly recompile...)

The tool also allows for extracting images that are inline (not downloaded dynamically by the flash animation, if so, anyway, you could as well download those images manually, you'd need the URL, though.)

The command line you can use is:

```
swf_dump -d my-animation.swf
```

Then your current folder will be littered with all the images that were found in the flash file. It extracts JPEGs and PNGs. The source can be compressed (SWF or CWF are supported.)

Now, you're on your own to compile that thing... The project is here and is in great need of updating (but Flash is kind of going out too...)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/sswf/